# How to open fancyBox in an iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a page with a navigation bar and a iframe. Is there a way to click a button in the main page so that the fancyBox pop-up would appear in the page that is in the iframe?

I mean something like this:

```
<div class="navigation">

 <a class="various" target="content" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="page.html">

  <button>

  </button>

 </a>

</div>

<iframe id="content" src="...">

</iframe>
```

Comment: Is the source in the iframe on the same domain? And why do you have a `button` inside an `a` tag?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same domain. Don't mind about the button, I copypasted just some fiddling I did and didn't remember to clean it up :)

Comment: How are you adding the fancybox in the iframe?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm asking. I'll try to explain this as well as I can: I have a index.html which has a button and an iframe.content. In the iframe is a page called page.html. I want to open the fancybox pop-up by clicking the button in the index.html so that the pop-up appears on top of the page.html in the iframe.content.

Comment: fancybox opening inside the iframe?? or fancybox opening with content from the iframe??

Comment: Opening inside the iframe. I have this very specific page layout and menu structure that would require this.